# Why does db.SaveChanges() not result in any errors, and no data saved, using EF, the generic repository framework with C# and MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Using [Long Le's Generic Generic Repository Framework/pattern](http://blog.longle.net/2013/05/11/genericizing-the-unit-of-work-pattern-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework-in-mvc/) and Entity Framework, I am unable to add new users in the following way - and no exceptions are thrown:

```
   public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
    {
        public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username,
           string password, string email, string passwordQuestion,
           string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved,
           object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
        {
            using (var db = new DBV001Context())
            {
                var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
                var encryptedPw = crypto.Compute(password);
                var user = db.Users.Create();

                user.MembershipTypeId = 7; 
                user.UserName = username;
                user.Email = email;
                user.Password = encryptedPw;
                user.PasswordSalt = crypto.Salt;
                //user.CreateDate = DateTime.Now; // set automatically in the db

                //user.CreateDate = new DateTime(1980,01,01,0,0,0,0);
                user.LastLoginDate = new DateTime(1980,01,01,0,0,0,0);
                user.LastActivityDate = new DateTime(1980,01,01,0,0,0,0);
                user.LastPasswordChangedDate = new DateTime(1980,01,01,0,0,0,0);
                user.LastLockoutDate = new DateTime(1980, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0);

                db.Users.Add(user);
                try
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();  // <----- nothing happens!
                }
                catch (SqlException e)
                {
                    if (e.Number == 2601) // Cannot insert duplicate key row in object error
                    {
                        // handle duplicate key error
                        //ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username already exists.");
                        throw e;

                    }
                    //throw; // throw exception if this exception is unexpected

                    //foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                    //{
                    //    Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                    //        eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                    //    //foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                    //    //{
                    //    //    logger.ErrorException(String.Format("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"", ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage), e);
                    //    //}
                    //}
## Heading ##
                    //throw e;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    while (ex.InnerException != null)
                        ex = ex.InnerException;
                    throw ex;
                    //ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
                }
```

I have SQL Server profiler running and there isn't even a call to the db. DB Connection is fine as in the previous line, `db.Users.Add(user);`, `Users` contains the collection of current users.

It has been some time since looking at this so some hints would be appreciated... thanks.

Comment: maybe an exception is thrown, but caught in your catch block, because it is an SqlException, but not with Number==2601?

Comment: There is a full catch later on though.

Comment: yup. however, any sql exceptions will be caught in the first block. therefore, for those the full catch will never be called.